# what is '#' mean on Postgressql.conf?

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to setup postgressql.conf file, but doesnt know what is '#' mean.

is '#' just to comment a parameter on postgressql.conf, or to reset to a default value ?

Comment: If it's at the beginning of a line, that line is a comment.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE

Answer (score 0):

Everything after `#` is a comment and ignored by PostgreSQL.

`postgresql.conf` contains (almost) all available database parameters, and most of them are commented out and set to the default value. That serves as documentation, along with the comments. That only has a meaning for the human reader.

If you comment out a line and reload PostgreSQL, the parameter will be reset to its default value.